# How to use Clozure CL on IPv6 only network?

Tags: common-lisp, clozure-cl

I've tried to replace SBCL with Clozure CL when working in IPv6 only network, but encountered an error like that:

```
MIGRATIONS> (ignore-errors (ccl:make-socket :remote-host "ya.ru" :remote-port 443))
NIL
#<CCL:NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD-EXISTS #x302005215E5D>
MIGRATIONS> (ignore-errors (ccl:make-socket :remote-host "ya.ru" :remote-port 443 :address-family :internet))
NIL
#<CCL:NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD-EXISTS #x3020052549AD>
MIGRATIONS> (ignore-errors (ccl:make-socket :remote-host "ya.ru" :remote-port 443 :address-family :internet6))
#<BASIC-TCP-STREAM ISO-8859-1 (SOCKET/16) #x3020051D4A9D>
```

The problem is that many libraries when using `CCL:MAKE-TCP-SOCKET` don't specify address-family or specify an `:internet`.

Is there is a way to patch `ccl:make-socket` at runtime to override this setting?

Answer (score 5):

**Advise a function**

Several implementations of Common Lisp allow *advising* (-> *patching*) of normal functions. Advising is a non-standard feature and different implementations provide it in slightly different ways. A related mechanism is standardized for CLOS generic functions with :before, :after and :around methods.

The purpose is to add one or more patches to a function, after it has been defined and without altering the original source code.

Typically this requires that the function call to this function is not *inlined*.

**The macro ADVISE in Clozure Common Lisp**

Patching functions in [Clozure CL](https://ccl.clozure.com) can be done with the macro `ADVISE`. See the documentation for [advising](https://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html#advising).

Let's say we have a function `FOOBAR`:

```
? (defun foobar (a b &key c (d :foobar)) (list a b c d))
FOOBAR
```

`FOOBAR` gets called inside `TEST`:

```
? (defun test (a) (foobar a 20 :c 30))
TEST

? (test 10)
(10 20 30 :FOOBAR)
```

We now want to patch `FOOBAR` such that named arg `:D` gets called with a different value.

We change the arglist to insert the new named argument after the two required args:

```
? (advise foobar (let ((arglist (list* (first arglist)
                                       (second arglist)
                                       :d :ipv6
                                       (cddr arglist))))
                   (:do-it))   ; calling the original function
          :when :around     ; advise around it
          :name :ipv6)      ; the name of this advise
#<Compiled-function (CCL::ADVISED 'FOOBAR) (Non-Global)  #x3020010D1CCF>
```

Now we can call our `TEST` function and it will call the *advised* function `FOOBAR`.

```
? (test 10)
(10 20 30 :IPV6)
```

**Advise for CCL:MAKE-SOCKET**

You could write a similar advise for [`CCL:MAKE-SOCKET`](https://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html#f_make-socket).

Untested:

```
(advise ccl:make-socket (let ((arglist (list* :address-family
                                              :internet6
                                              arglist)))
                          (:do-it))
        :when :around
        :name :internet6)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done!

First make a copy of the original make-socket

```
(IN-PACKAGE :ccl)
(DEFPARAMETER original-make-socket #'make-socket)
```

Then redefine make-socket. Note: You will have to provide the full spec for all keyword parameters. As it is, I've used only the ones from your question for demonstration.

```
(defun make-socket (&key (remote-host "defau.lt") 
                         (remote-port 443) 
                         (address-family :internet6))
  (declare (ignore address-family))
  (format t "Calling new make-socket with address-family as internet6!")
  (funcall original-make-socket 
           :remote-host remote-host 
           :remote-port remote-port 
           :address-family :internet6))
```

This will signal a ***continuable* error**.

Type `:go` at the repl to continue.
This will successfully patch make-socket.

Now any calls to make-socket will be to the new definition. Try:

```
(IN-PACKAGE :cl-user)
(ccl:make-socket :remote-host "ya.ru" :remote-port 443 :address-family :IRRELEVANT)
```

---

Another way to do it, would be to override the global variable `*warn-if-redefine-kernel*` before redefining make-socket.

```
(setf *warn-if-redefine-kernel* nil)
```

This will avoid the continuable error signal, and straight patch the kernel function.